# how can I suppress the "dtype" line when printing a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and need to print the output of some aggregations and such.

For example, a line in my script has:

```
pd.f_type = inventory['fruit'].value_counts()
print(f_type)
```

And its output like this:

```
apple         2
watermelon    1
pineapple     1
grapefruit    1
orange        1
Name: fruit, dtype: int64
```

How I can I remove the last line with "Name..."? I don't need it. I just need to see the actual output. Do I need to print with a for loop or something?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the removal of the last line is just for the sake of output, you can do like this:

```
f_type.to_string()
```

However, be careful with using `.to_string()` on large dataframes, because it will convert and print the entire dataframe, not just the amount of rows specified in `pd.options.display.max_rows`.

In addition to that, if you have a lot of columns the output will be pretty messed up. In that case you should probably do a print loop instead.

Answer (score 3):

in your case you can also do:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(f_type))
```

The name and dtype underneath the data is printed out only for `pandas.Series`

Comment: you can call `to_frame` on series `print(f_type.to_frame())`

Comment: This adds an empty column name with "0".  Now I would need to suppress that